# css placeholder transitions not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

has any one else had any issues getting transitions to work with placeholders in Firefox. I've been searching but can't find any duplicate issues. I'm thinking it might be because im running Windows XP but not sure. Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fJqCG/). Works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work because when you focus the field Firefox actually *removes* the placeholder text completely so it doesn't even get the opportunity to animate.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case anymore. I just updated the CodePen. You see if I comment out the call to color:transparent; than the placeholder stays in place until a value is typed. It seems that the  transition is not working.